# How to add JVM arguments for Spring Boot project in VS Code?

Tags: java, spring, visual-studio-code, jvm-arguments

I'm trying out VS Code by moving a project I did on Eclipse to it. I had a run configuration in Eclipse for this project which had the following JVM arguments:

```
--module-path lib/javafx-sdk-13/lib --add-modules=javafx.controls
```

Of course this "lib" folder and its contents followed to the new VS Code project folder but I don't know where to put those JVM arguments in vsCode, the equivalent of the run configurations with Eclipse essentially.  I tried putting them in the args section of the `launch.json` file with no success.

I am using the spring boot dashboard to launch the project if that makes a difference.

Here is my `launch.json`:

```
{
"configurations": [
    {
        "type": "java",
        "name": "Spring Boot-BudgetApplication<budget>",
        "request": "launch",
        "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
        "console": "internalConsole",
        "mainClass": "com.someone.budget.BudgetApplication",
        "projectName": "budget",
        "args": ["--module-path","lib/javafx-sdk-13/lib","--add-modules=javafx.controls"]
    }
]
```

}

Comment: Even just running the main method without the spring boot dashboard does not work.

Comment: -D`ARG_NAME`=`ARG_VALUE` I.e.: -Dhttp.proxy="http://myproxy.url"

Comment: is that not just for Spring properties?  Not sure how that would translate to JVM arguments to point to the JavaFX files and add the controls module?

Comment: JVM Args are quite simple `--ARG` is destinated to the `Jar` you run, `-DargName` is an `JVM` Argument. Keep in mind, your code (your jar) can access the JVM Args.

Comment: is this the right syntax? "args": "-D--module-path lib/javafx-sdk-13/lib --add-modules=javafx.controls"

Comment: Nop `-Dmodule-path=lib/javafx-sdk-13/lib` `-Dadd-modules=javafx.controls` maybe `--Dmodule-path=lib/javafx-sdk-13/lib` `--Dadd-modules=javafx.controls`

Comment: none of those work

Comment: No, --module-path is a [regular argument of the Java command](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/specs/man/java.html). Whatever is passed to -D becomes a system property. There is a whole lot of miscommunication going on here and a whole lot of guess work. I think the arguments deal is a big red herring, isn't this a more generic "How do I get stuff to run using the Spring Boot Dashboard VSC plugin" ? If so... you must be getting an error of some kind, so share it.

Comment: Does it work if you just run the app outside of VSCode ?

Comment: "Error: JavaFX runtime components are missing, and are required to run this application". Typical "I don't know where the libs are" error.

Comment: this app works perfectly in eclipse because i can just add those arguments in the run configuration's JVM arguments

Comment: Ok, so your problem is into the VSCode plugin.

Comment: It is not, as I get the same issue just running the main method normally without the plugin.  Again, I just need to know how to pass JVM arguments to a Java app with vsCode.  If it can at least run I'll worry about the spring boot dashboard plugin later.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The solution was placing the args in the vmArgs section like so :

```
"vmArgs": "--module-path=lib/javafx-sdk-13/lib --add-modules=javafx.controls"
```

Comment: This works with the spring boot dashboard plugin as well btw.

Comment: Could you please add steps Where to add this?

Comment: @MehrajMalik In the project's [launch.json](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/java/java-debugging)

Answer (score 3):

Just add it in the launch.json file.

```json
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "java",
            "name": "Application",
            "request": "launch",
            "mainClass": "mypackage.Application",
            "projectName": "myproject",
            "vmArgs": "-Darg1=60000 -Darg2=120000"
        }
    ],
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I know this question was for springboot, but wanted to add for **standalone** *java* apps, you can just add **args** to *launch.json*

```json
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "java",
            "name": "Application",
            "request": "launch",
            "mainClass": "mypackage.Application",
            "projectName": "myproject",
            "args": ["60000","120000"]
        }
    ],
}
```