# Java 9 Modules VScode

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, java-9, java-module

I've been trying to work on Java 9's modules and I've been using VSCode to do so. I found no resource(webpage, YT video) or anything describing how the modules(Not JAR files) can be added to the build path in VSCode.

Any link to resources or answers are much appreciated

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There's a [configuration option](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/java/java-debugging#_configuration-options) called `modulePaths` in launch.json, which specifies modulepaths for launching the JVM. You may try it then debug the project to make the configuration effective.

For your reference, here's [an example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60043017/vscode-how-to-add-jvm-argument-for-spring-boot-project).